# Checking webElement for not containing text, with case insensitive in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, case-insensitive

I need to check a webElement if not contains a list of strings; those strings are taken from a json file, and to avoid typos, I need to check that the webElement does NOT contain those strings, no matter if in the json file are written with or without capital letters.

So, for example, i need to do

```
// values is an array containing strings to check, e.g values = ["i", "nEed", "A", "Doctor"] 
values.map(singleValue => {
    expect(webElement).not.have.text(singleValue)
}
```

and if the `webElement` has 'I need a Doctor' as text, every check should return `false`.

Well, `.not.have.text` obviously doesn't work, because it does not exists; for several reasons related with throwing errors, I cannot use `.not.contains('string', {matchCase: false})` , because it stops after the first error found (while for example `.not.contain('string')` doesn't, but it's not case insensitive).

I also cannot use `toLowerCase()` on `webElement`, because `webElement`...well it's a web element, and not a text, and since I do this check on several places and different pages, I don't know in what part of this webElement is the text (to obtain the webElement i used `cy.get('idOfTheWebElement')`. )

Is there a way I still don't know to check values in insensitive case?

Comment: is `not.to.include.text` helped?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I tried but the result is `true` :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the text of the webelement, you can convert it to a string, lowercase it, and then compare it to your own string, which is also lowercase. If you convert both values to lowercase, you can just iterate over every element and check the strings in an if statement. If you're trying to return the ones which do not have the text, it's as simple as reversing the logic of a match in your if statement.

I do not use webElement or Cypress and therefor can only give you this wall of text explaining the general idea of matching strings without case sensitivity. It should help, but I cannot provide you with example code.